# How to decouple processing servers from database

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am building an application which takes in requests from users via web interface and then performs some processing and returns the result whenever available.

Here is a simple overview of the current architecture:

[image: Architecture]

The web application adds the request to multiple collections in MongoDB with the `processed` field set to False. Then there are processing servers for each collection, which poll their collections to check if there are any unprocessed entries. If yes, the servers then perform the processing which takes some time and also some cost (external API calls) and then save the result back in the database (`output_data`)and set `processed` to True.

Now, the problem I have:

1. I am unable to scale up the processing servers for each module, because if I run two servers then there is a chance that the same entry is processed twice and would incur more cost for me.
2. I also want to decouple the processing servers from the database, as I want to use the same processing servers with different databases too (ex: for different customers)

I do not know much about queues and pub/sub architecture. I think some sort of queue architecture would be useful in achieving the above, but not sure how to handle duplicate messages.

Please let me know what architecture would be useful in avoiding the problems above. I would prefer the solution to be cloud provider agnostic, but if really needed I would like to go with AWS.

Update:
My current development stack is Python, Flask, MongoDB, Docker.

Comment: Is the web app actually waiting for the result? Or does it fire-and-forget, and then offer a separate way to check for results? In other words, is that part of the process designed to support an asynchronous approach?

Comment: Yes, the web app is asynchronous, the user can view the results later by selecting the request from a list. I've found alex's answer below to be perfect for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use *a message queue*, which will solve many of your problems. For example, [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com), here you can find python [libraries](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#python-dev) for working with it.

Instead of polling, your working processes will simply wait for a new message to arrive, eliminating the problem of duplicate processing. They can also send the result back to the message queue and the saving worker will save them to any (different) databases. I find that introducing message queues fits well with your architecture as [publish/subscribe](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different queues based on your requirement in the below architecture.

- Redis Pub/Sub: https://redis.io/topics/pubsub
- Kafka/RabitMQ: You can check which tool fits your needs.
- AWS SQS: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ (If you want to use the queue without the hassle of installation and maintenance. Different cloud provides queuing mechanisms.
- In Memory Queue: Drawback is this is volatile and the queue will be
  lost when the system restarts/crashes. Can be used if you have some
  mechanism of re-creating the queue if required.
  [image: You can use the Queue based on your requirements]

Comment: How to handle the case where sending a message to the queue from the backend fails but saving the request id in database succeeds?

Comment: You can publish bin logs from DB and push it to Queue to ensure the Backend only needs to publish to DB successfully.

Another approach would be to simply have a retry with exponential backoff while writing to queue. This should help to drastically reduce errors while writing to Queue.